# Java Average From File

Tags: java, file, loops

I'm trying to do a simple program to find the average of a series of numbers in a text document, I have most of it down but I am having an issue with writing to the same variable in my while statement. My code looks like this.

```
public static void processFile (String filename) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    try (BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("scores.txt")))) {
        String line;
        int lineNum = countLines("scores.txt");
        int [] allNums = new int [lineNum];
        while (( line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
           int i = 0;
           allNums[i] = Integer.parseInt(line);
           average(allNums);
           System.out.println(allNums[i]);

           }

         System.out.println(average(allNums));
    }
}
public static double average(int[] avg){
double sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < avg.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + avg[i];
}
return sum / avg.length;
}
`public static int countLines(String filename) throws IOException {
    int cnt;
    try (LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(new 
FileReader(filename))) {
        cnt = 0;
        String lineRead = "";
        while ((lineRead = reader.readLine()) != null) {}
        cnt = reader.getLineNumber();
        }
    return cnt;
}`
```

Instead of finding the average of the numbers in the file, it takes the last number written to the array and divides it by the number of numbers in the file. I have looked up my problem but can't find a solution that has worked. Also I know I have become a little convoluted and inefficient with my coding, particularly finding the number of lines, but it's a small file and I would like it to work before I make it more efficient.

Comment: You are not incrementing `i` in your `while` loop.

Comment: Atri is right.  Move `int i = 0;` up, outside the `while` loop, and put `i++;` at the bottom of the loop.  Otherwise, you just write to the first element of the array, over and over.

Answer (score 1):

Take `average(allNums);` out of the loop.
And yes, you need to increment `i`.

Consider getting rid of `i`, and `countLines` all together, and using an `ArrayList` instead of array.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code:

```
while (( line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
           int i = 0;
           allNums[i] = Integer.parseInt(line);
           average(allNums);
           System.out.println(allNums[i]);
}
```

to:

```
int i = 0;   
while (( line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {          
           allNums[i] = Integer.parseInt(line);           
           System.out.println(allNums[i]);
           i++;
}
average(allNums);
```

You need to:

- Initialize `i=0` outside the loop.
- Increment `i` inside the loop.
- Move `average(allNums);` outside the loop if you don't want it to print average of numbers on reading each number.

Looks like you want to print average after reading each number, in that case you can keep your `average(allNums);` line inside the loop.